# Could not find UpdatePanel in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'Pan22'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="datepicker.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.datepicker" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(
  function () {
      $("#dater").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
      });
  }
);
</script>
</head>
 <body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>

    <p>
        Pick a Date:
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="dater" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="dater_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the question???

Comment: getting an error on console " Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'Pan22'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel."

Comment: Once i update date input other input panel are not updating

Comment: You'll have no luck getting an answer here, as you've posted this using the Classic ASP tag. Try editing your post and add the [tag:c#] and [tag:asp.net] tags.

Comment: There is no where near enough info for us to help you with this. Where/when are you getting this error? Where is `Pan22`? There seems to be no reference to it in your code.